# Price rendering with _clone suffix

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, template

I have a template that is only rendering my product price with the _clone suffix.

This is causing the Javascript update function `reload` to fail because it cannot identify any place on the page where the original ID is used.

The script is looking for `"product-price-1743"` while the only thing on the page is `"product-price-1743_clone"`

ideally, I would like to adjust the template so that it drops the clone suffix, but I don't know why it's not using a blank suffix first.

The rendered HTML as an example

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-1743_clone">
  <span class="price" itemprop="price" content="9.99">$9.99</span>                                                            
</span>
```

The Failing JAvascript test (line 650 of product.js)

```
if ($(pair.value)) {
```

Where `pair.value` equals `product-price-1743`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clone suffix is used for product with options (either custom option or configurable product), for these product magento show the price in the upper part of the product page (as usual) and replicate "clone" the price near/after the options choice (should be in a block called "wrapper_bottom").

If you modify the template and remove the price the js will not work.

You can try the base template to see the "two" price and restore the "not cloned one" in your template.

Now you can check of your scripts works and if so you can "hide" the "not cloned part" so that the js works and ou see only one price in the page.

Answer (score 1):

check for below code

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone'); ?>
```

if your template contains that `_clone` as third param then that `_clone` will be added in price span class